# Не выводятся данные в ListView android

Tags: android, listview

При выведении данных в listview ничего не происходит, для выведения использую следующую конструкцию:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);    
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

сам listview объявлен таким образом:

```
     <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/lvMain"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Comment: title не бывает пустым, то есть массив заполняется данными

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в **wrap_content**. Измени на **match_parent**

Comment: Увы, не помогло

Comment: еще вариант написать adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); прописать после list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: покажи больше кода, или всю разметку или весь код, покажи какие данные ты передаешь в список, может он пустой

Comment: также безрезультатно. может дело в том, что я вызываю создание списка в AsyncTask? Но я создал отдельную кнопку, которая только создает адаптер и передает его в список, но при нажатии на эту кнопку приложение закрывается

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
     JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("list");
     str = new String[jArray.length()];
     ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
     String name = null;
     for(int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
     {
            JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
      int id = jObj.getInt("id");
      String title = jObj.getString("title");

Comment: выводи в консоль или проверь дебагером или есть данные в title